# Class structure possibly needing implementation of composition to mimic multiple inheritance

Tags: php, oop, design-patterns, multiple-inheritance

Here's the basic premise, I'm using an active record pattern for db objects, and I think I need some direction how to organize these classes.  And also in general how I could potentially split up my class structure.  Hopefully I don't explain this too terribly.  If composition pattern is the way to go I may need a little hand holding on a way to implement it.

Let's say there's the `ActiveRecord` base class, at the bottom of the totem pole that deals with mapping objects to the db and the db to objects.

A child of `ActiveRecord` is a sort of generic `User` class, that deals with user sessions, logins, encryption of the password field on save and such.

Another child of `ActiveRecord` is a `ActiveRecordButSlightlyMoreAdvanced` class.  Usually this class has nothing to do with `User`, but here's my issue.

I want to have a subclass that wants to be essentially a combination of `User` and `ActiveRecordButSlightlyMoreAdvanced`; `UserButSlightlyMoreAdvanced`, without having to copy paste all of the methods from `User`.  It doesn't make sense for `User` to extend `ActiveRecordButSlightlyMoreAdvanced`, as it'd require essentially overriding a bunch of methods that have undesirable behavior for `User`. 
It would make sense for `UserButSlightlyMoreAdvanced` to extend `ActiveRecordButSlightlyMoreAdvanced`, but I'd have to copy and paste a bunch of methods from `User`.

I know some people think better with pictures, so here's the structure illustrated.

Base

```
class ActiveRecord
{
    ....
}
```

Child

```
class User extends ActiveRecord
{
    ....
}
```

Also Child

```
class ActiveRecordButSlightlyMoreAdvanced extends ActiveRecord
{
    ....
}
```

The Problem

```
class UserButSlightlyMoreAdvanced extends User AND ActiveRecordButSlightlyMoreAdvanced
{
        :( :( :(
}
```

I've been thinking about this problem for about a month now and cannot think of a solution that doesn't place burden of maintaining the objects dually if there's a change to how one of them implements saving.  I'm going to experiment with a few solutions over the next couple of days and possibly post what I think was best in this situation.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you meant to say this:

```
class UserButSlightlyMoreAdvanced extends User AND ActiveRecordButSlightlyMoreAdvanced 
{
    :) :) :)
}
```

If that is the case, look into traits http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php

Comment: You're right ><. I feel like my slight typo destroyed my question a bit.

Answer (score 0):

You might try using the strategy pattern.  In this case you would create your class:

```
class UserButSlightlyMoreAdvanced extends ActiveRecord implements ActiveRecordButSlightlyMoreAdvancedStrategy
{
    private $_strategy;

    public function useStrategy(ActiveRecordButSlightlyMoreAdvancedStrategy $s) {
        $this->_strategy = $s;
    }
}
```

and make your strategy class:

```
interface ActiveRecordButSlightlyMoreAdvancedStrategy
{
        // Define what this should do here
}
```

Make a strategy class that implements the above interface.

```
class ActiveRecordButSlightlyMoreAdvanced implements ActiveRecordButSlightlyMoreAdvancedStrategry {
    // Do stuff here
}
```

Now when you call those advanced methods, both classes implement the same interface, but the UserButSlightlyMoreAdvanced class just passes the requests through to the strategy object:

```
class UserButSlightlyMoreAdvanced extends ActiveRecord implements ActiveRecordButSlightlyMoreAdvancedStrategy
    {
        private $_strategy;

        public function useStrategy(ActiveRecordButSlightlyMoreAdvancedStrategy $s) {
            $this->_strategy = $s;
        }

        public function someSlightlyMoreAdvancedFunction () {
             return $this->_strategy->someSlightlyMoreAdvancedFunction():
        }
    }
```

Hope that helps.